# Linear Recurrence In Faster Time

Tags: matrices, recurrence-relations, contest-math, exponentiation

I am trying to solve this linear recurrence using matrix exponentiation:-

$$f(n) = 2f(n-1) - f(n-2) + c,$$

where $c$ is a constant.

What I have come up with is this -

Let the matrix $M$ be

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & -1 & 1\\ 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Now, we have

$$M^{n-4}\cdot\begin{bmatrix}f(4)\\f(3)\\c\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}f(n)\\f(n-1)\\c\end{bmatrix}. $$

I have used this to solve the recurrence.
However, I was wondering: since there is a constant in the recurrence, is there any way to solve it using a $2\times 2$ matrix $M$ instead of the $3\times 3$ one which I have used?

Any suggestions would be valued, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f(n)-2f(n-1)+f(n-2)=(f(n)-f(n-1))-(f(n-1)-f(n-2))=\nabla^2[f](n)$ is a backward second difference. We have a second order nonhomogeneous difference equation $\nabla^2[f](n)=c$.

Note that if we had some sequence $g(n)=n^2$ we observe:
$$g(n)-g(n-1)=n^2-(n-1)^2=2n-1$$ so $$(g(n)-g(n-1))-(g(n-1)-g(n-2))=(2n-1)-(2(n-1)-1)=2$$ which means $n^2$ is a particular solution to $\nabla^2[f](n)=2$.

By linearity, our inhomogeneous part $c$ gives us a particular solution $f_p(n)=\frac12cn^2$. If we look at $f$ in our affine solution space to $\nabla^2[f](n)$ and subtract $f_p$ we get solutions to the *homogeneous* problem $\nabla^2[f](n)=0$.

This is all in analogy with the standard theory of linear differential equations.

---

Note that you can also compute terms of this sequence even faster in isolation using the fact that the kernel of $\nabla^2[f]$ is spanned by $\{1,n\}$ hence you know our solution is of the form $f(n)=\frac{c}2 n^2+an+b$; note this gives $$b=f(0)\\a=f(1)-f(0)-\frac{c}2$$... so if you're given initial conditions $f(0),f(1)$ you can compute the $n$-th term using $f(n)=\frac{c}2n^2+an+b$ with $a,b$ computed as above.

Comment: This is the most creative solution yet! How did you figure out that a quadratic solution may exist, and when can this approach be applicable?

Answer (score 3):

Try to make a variable change of type:
$$ g(n) = f(n) + n^{\alpha} a $$. Try $\alpha$ from $0, 1, 2 ..$.

Here is the case where $\alpha = 0, 1$ does not work. But $\alpha = 2, a = -\frac{c}{2}$ works!

Then $g(n)$ satisfies:

$$
g(n) = 2g(n-1) - g(n-2)
$$

Comment: This works in this case because $f(n)-2f(n-1)+f(n-2)$ is the second difference operator. When this is applied to $n^2$, this gives a constant, which can be used to cancel out $c$. If the recurrence were just about anything else (try $f(n) = 2f(n-1)+f(n-2)$), this would not work.

Comment: In your case, I think $g(n)=f(n) +c/2$ would work. $\alpha = 0$. In fact, you could do this trick for any polynomial additive term.

Comment: Thanks for this approach! I was wondering: is this a general method, or only applicable in this situation? When can we assume g(n)=f(n)+(n^x)a?

Comment: Quite general. In fact, you could add a polynomial term with high degree, then just solve a linear equation to equalize the coefficients. But in practice where cases are quite simple, doing $(n^\alpha)a$ is enough.

Comment: Only applicable to this recurrence or a similar on as I noted. It won't wotk for f(n) - 2f(n-1)+f(n-2)+c.

Comment: @Sisi : putting g(n) = f(n) + c/2 doesn't work out. In fact, putting any g(n) = f(n) + k*c doesn't work out.

Comment: @MahatmaGandhi, I was saying for $f(n) = 2f(n-1) - f(n-2)$. Anyway, just try $\alpha$ integers from small to big.

Comment: @Sisi Thanks for the reply but I think you've made a calculation mistake.. it doesn't work out for this recurrence.

Comment: for $f(n)-2f(n-1)-f(n-2)=c$, the particular solution $f(n)=-c/2$ works since $-c/2+c+c/2=c$, so @Sisi is correct

Comment: @oldrinb.. reread Sisi's comment, it has been written for f(n) - 2f(n-1) + f(n-2)

Comment: @MahatmaGandhi you are confused, unfortunately; martycohen was suggesting that though this method worked here it would not find a particular solution to $f(n)=2f(n-1)+f(n-2)+c$, which is identical to $f(n)-2f(n-1)-f(n-2)=c$; Sisi was correct, however, that substituting $g(n)=f(n)+c/2$ reduces that to $g(n)-2g(n-1)-g(n-2)=0$

Comment: so @martycohen was incorrect and you appear to have become lost at some point

Comment: That's true. Thinking a bit more about this, I have concluded that if the recurrence is not like a k-th difference, then you can eliminate a constant; if it is, you can subtract a power of n to do it.

Comment: @oldrinb, Thanks for supporting me. Anyway, it does not matter what the exact solution is. Once you understand the method, it is pretty general.